# awk or sed extract each number of column alone

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Hello i want to extract each line count to a file by command.

```
4495125 94307025    giovy115p@live.it   94307025.094307025  12443
stazla  deva1a23@gmail.com  1992/.:\1
1447585 gioao_87@hotmail.it h1st@1
saknit  tomboro@seznam.cz   1233    1990
_______________________________________________________
5column.txt
4495125 94307025    giovy115p@live.it   94307025.094307025  12443
_______________________________________________________
4column.txt 
saknit  tomboro@seznam.cz   1233    1990
_______________________________________________________
3column.txt 
stazla  deva1a23@gmail.com  1992/.:\1
1447585 gioao_87@hotmail.it h1st@1
```

i need code to do this job please!!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. We need to see the effort.

Comment: dmitryro i have tested with simple script
awk -F : -v OFS=':' '{print $1, $2, $3}'

Comment: can you explain why you used the field separators? your given sample doesn't seem to need it..

Comment: hint: use `NF` to form file name and see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html for redirecting print output...

Comment: You don't even explain what "each line count" is; we can guess but this is far from clear.

Comment: The test data is suspiciously similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056103/set-an-external-variable-in-awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` could help you in same.

```
awk '{print > NF"column.txt"}'  Input_file
```

Output it will create 3 files named `5column.txt`, `4column.txt` and `3column.txt`.