# Set an external variable in awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have written a script in which I want to count the number of columns in data.txt . My problem is I am unable to set the x in awk script.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
while read p; do
  x=1;
  echo $p | awk -F' ' '{x=NF}'
  echo $x;
  file="$x"".txt";
  echo $file;
  done <$1
```

data.txt file:

```
4495125 94307025    giovy115p@live.it   94307025.094307025  12443
stazla  deva1a23@gmail.com  1992/.:\1
1447585 gioao_87@hotmail.it h1st@1
saknit  tomboro@seznam.cz   1233    1990
```

Expected output:

```
5.txt
3.txt
3.txt
4.txt
```

My output:

```
1.txt
1.txt
1.txt
1.txt
```

Comment: This question is about setting the external variable in awk script. I am not simply printing it. I have to use the variable x for creating a file. So I have to set it.

Comment: This is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055478/awk-or-sed-extract-each-number-of-column-alone -- does your professor allow you to use Stack Overflow to solve your homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just *cannot* import variable set in `Awk` to a shell context. In your example the value set inside `x` containing `NF` will be not reflected outside.

Either you need to use command substitution(`$(..)`) syntax to get the value of `NF` and use it later

```
x=$(echo "$p" | awk '{print NF}')
```

Now `x` will contain the column count in each of the line. Note that you don't need to use `-F' '` which is the default de-limiter in `awk`.

Besides your requirement can be fully done in `Awk` itself.

```
awk 'NF{print NF".txt"}' file
```

Here the `NF{..}` is to ensure that the actions inside `{..}` are applied only to non-empty rows. The for each row we print the length and append the extension `.txt` along with it.

Answer (score 1):

Awk processes a line at a time -- processing each line in a separate Awk script inside a shell `while read` loop is horrendously inefficient.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Maybe something like this:

```
awk '{ print >(NF ".txt") }' data.txt
```

to create a file with the five-column rows in `5.txt`, the four-column ones in `4.txt`, the three-column rows in `2.txt`, etc for each unique column count.

The Awk variable `NF` contains the number of fields (by default, Awk splits fields on runs of whitespace -- use `-F` to change to some other separator) and the expression `(NF ".txt")` simply produces a string catenation of the number of fields with the suffix `.txt` which we pass as a file name to the `print` redirection.

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
while read p; do p=($p); echo "${#p[@]}.txt"; done < file
```

or shorter:

```
while read -a p; do echo "${#p[@]}.txt"; done < file
```

Output:

```
5.txt
3.txt
3.txt
4.txt
```